# Mule Server 3.7.0 error: "Failure to find com.mulesoft.weave:mule-plugin-weave_2.11:jar:3.7.0"

Tags: maven, mule

I am trying to build a mule app with Maven using `Mule Server 3.7.0 EE`.
I'm erroring out when trying to add to my app the `Data-weave Transformer`.

I added to my `pom.xml` file this dependency:

```
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
         <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>${mule.version}</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>
```

but I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project370: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test:project370:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.mulesoft.weave:mule-plugin-weave_2.11:jar:3.7.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing `mvn install -U` where `-U` would force your maven dependencies to be updated.

If you are using the maven m2 plugin for eclipse you can right click on your project `Maven -> Update Project` make sure that "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" is enabled then click OK.

Also check [this link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb) for the documentation on configuring your repository properly.

Comment: now I am getting this error: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project pro: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.test:pro:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mulesoft.weave:mule-plugin-weave_2.11:jar:3.7.0 in Central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) `  it's seems like it's just  not available there, so where could I find the specific  jar?

Comment: but I have no problem when I build with server 3.7.2 EE?

Comment: so the only solution is to create an account to access MuleSoft Enterprise Maven customer repository?

Comment: tried downloading but the jar above is missing there, does it mean that jar doesn't exist and data-weave is not supported Mule ESB Enterprise runtime version 3.7.0?

Comment: How to add jar via maven repository? I have this `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>` but no luck,

Comment: I tried this `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.mulesoft.weave -DartifactId=mule-plugin-weave_2.11 -Dversion=3.7.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file` but I'm getting this `Unable to read jar manifest from /home/user/.m2/repository/com/mulesoft/weave/mule-plugin-weave_2.11/3.7.0/mule-plugin-weave_2.11-3.7.0.jar`

Comment: it doesn't contain a pom

Comment: have tried using the `dataweave transformer` in a mule app ?

Comment: I get this error: `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dw:transform-message'`??

Comment: yes it did,thanks for that, but now does that mean I cant use 3.7.0 version of dataweave?